# How do I append things on list through recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I have this code:

```
def positive(A):
    if len(A)==0:
        return 0
    else:
        if A[0]>0:
            return A [0]+positive(A[1:])
        else:
            return positive(A[1:])
```

Theoretically, when I input a list of numbers, it will return the list of positive numbers. For example, when I pass `[2,5,-3,-5,2,-6]` it will return `[2,5,2]`. But in my code, what happens is that the positive values are evaluated so this returns `9`. I think my problem is that in `A [0]+positive(A[1:])` line but I don't know how to change it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @DeepSpace For me, im doing this for practice as i can easily solve this using for loops but there are just some algorithms that works better with recurssion (to minimize storage and all).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should return a `list` for every case,

- so for the empty list case do `return []` and `if not A` to test for empty list
- use `A[:1]` to get a list of one element instead of `A[0]` which is an `int` ( `[A[0]]` does same)
- simplified a bit the `else`, you don't need them if the previous branches does `return`

```
def positive(A):
    if not A:
        return []
    if A[0] > 0:
        return A[:1] + positive(A[1:])
    return positive(A[1:])
```

---

A nice idea from the comments is to use the boolean condition directly as the index to slice with

- if `A[0]>0` is `True`, then `int(True) == 1` so your slice `A[:1]`
- if `A[0]>0` is `False`, then `int(False) == 0` so your slice `A[:0]` which is empty

```
def positive(A):
    if not A:
        return []
    return A[:int(A[0] > 0)] + positive(A[1:])
```

With inline `if`

```
def positive(A):
    return A[:int(A[0] > 0)] + positive(A[1:]) if A else []
```

Comment: If you want to be really clever: `return A[:int(A[0] > 0)] + positive(A[1:])`

Comment: `positive = lambda A: A[:int(A[0] > 0)] + positive(A[1:]) if A else []` :-P